# Facebook Authentication, Strict OAuth Mode: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: php, facebook

Got an issue, when I am trying to login with php sdk with Strict mode in OAuth section enabled.

So basically what I did so far:

Created a fresh app, so I could test properly.

Where in:
**Settings->App Domains** I've put `sub.domain.com` and `domain.com`

On the **Products->Facebook Login->Settings** I have entered the following valid OAuth Urls

```
https://sub.domain.com/fbtest/
https://sub.domain.com/fbtest/login.php
https://sub.domain.com/fbtest/fb-response.php
```

Then got the code from that page - copy/paste - except the `$app_id` and `$app_secret` and `$redirect_to` variables and a `session_start()`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

and constructed the pages above `login.php` and `fb-response.php`

I tested the app  with **Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs** set to **No** and as expected I got a Access Token on `fb-response.php` page.

When I selected the **Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs** to **Yes** though, I got the following Exception message

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

The domains in the example are real and online.

I double checked all the fields on the app, but they seems ok to me, so I am stuck so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this was a bug in the facebook graph-php package. The version 5.6.2 will fix this issue.

https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/939#issuecomment-365780367